# "Confess!" VS "Admit it!"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

As almost everybody knows, the verb "confess" means "**to admit**", especially to the police, that you have done something wrong or illegal.

But, Longman Dictionary says:

> In everyday English, people usually say admit rather than confess:
> I know it was him – he admitted it.
> I admit I’m not very good with money. [Source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/confess)

Now, I was wondering which choice sounds naturally idiomatic in the example below:

> - I know you have an affair with her Samuel. .............

a. Confess! 
b. Admit it!

Prior to reading this register, I used to simply say:  "Confess!" But now, I think it is something more related to legislative atmosphere than everyday speech.

Please kindly make me aware about it.

Comment: In this context either seems equally good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Confess" is very formal, and as well as usage in law has connections to [religious confession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confession_(religion)). Yelling "confess!" sounds like something from the catholic [inquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisition) of the middle ages and definitely not something anyone would use in modern, everyday speech.

"Admit it" is 'everyday' speech. It could be formal - 'confessions' in law are sometimes referred to as admissions or admissions of guilt. But it is common enough to be used informally too.

It might be worth noting that a British English colloquialism '*[fess up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fessed+up)*' is an informal, slang expression derived from the word 'confess' and means to admit or confess.